# Am I supposed to create a child theme for every theme I use?

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

I just learned about child themes recently and was wondering if creating a child theme for every theme I create is necessary. I just find it weird how other themes work okay without child themes, and others do not.

Comment: If you don't want to create child them then simply download any free theme and make direct editing in that theme. You don't need to afraid to make direct editing in any theme until that theme don't provide any update.

Comment: The whole point of child themes is that they give you a route to modify an existing theme without editing it directly.  _Do not_ edit the main theme, unless it is a theme you have written and maintain.  Whenever there is an update, which may be for security reasons, you will overwrite your changes.

Answer (score 4):

Child themes are not the only way to extend a theme, not even the best.

Many themes offer hooks: actions and filters. You can use these to change the output per plugin.

Let’s say you have a theme named *Acme*, and its `index.php` contains the following code:

```
get_header();

do_action( 'acme.loop.before', 'index' );
?>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php
            /*
             * Run the loop to output the posts.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called loop-index.php and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
            ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->

<?php
do_action( 'acme.loop.after', 'index' );

do_action( 'acme.sidebar.before', 'index' );
get_sidebar();
do_action( 'acme.sidebar.after', 'index' );

get_footer();
```

Now you can write a small plugin to add wrappers (maybe for a second background image) around these specific areas:

```
add_action( 'acme.loop.before', function( $template ) {
    if ( 'index' === $template )
        print "<div class='extra-background'>";
});

add_action( 'acme.loop.after', function( $template ) {
    if ( 'index' === $template )
        print "</div>";
});
```

Add other, separate plugins for other modifications.

This has four benefits:

1. You can turn off the extra behavior in your plugin administration if you don't want it anymore. In contrast to child themes, you do that for each plugin separately, you don't have to turn every customization like you do when you have only one child theme.
2. It is much faster than a child theme, because when WordPress is searching for a template and it cannot find it, it will search in both, child and parent themes. That cannot happen when there is no child theme.
3. It is easier to debug when something goes wrong. With child themes, it is hard to see where an error is coming from, child or parent theme. Or both, that's extra fun.
4. Safe updates. Sometimes, when you update a parent theme, the child theme doesn't work anymore, or worse: it works differently. It might even raise a fatal error, because you are using a function in the child theme that isn't available in the parent theme anymore.

**Summary:** Use hooks whenever you can, use a child theme only if the parent theme doesn't offer a good hook. Ask the theme author to add the missing hook. If you can offer a valid use case, I am sure s/he will implement it.

Answer (score 1):

For me the rule of thumb is am I extending/revising an existing theme? If so I'll want to be able to update the theme (assuming it's well supported) without nuking all my changes. You can read more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) in the codex.

If I'm creating something custom I find it best to just use my own starter theme  (or something like [Underscores](http://underscores.me/)) and edit the theme itself.